# glyphicons have sudden disappeared on my website

Tags: glyphicons

On my website the glyphicons have sudden vanished.

It has been working correctly for a long time. Since today most of them have vanished.
I have uploaded them again and again.

Comment: What site? Uploaded where? How are you uploading them? Please provide more information.

Comment: Website: http://classifieds.paibkk.com
The glyphicons came with the program oc-classifieds.

Comment: On my end, all the glyphicons are loading properly...

Comment: With both Google Chrome and Mozilla I don't see the glyphicons on http://classifieds.paibkk.com. On a similar website I do see them. Funny..